# TCL_REGEXP::How to grep words from tcl variable and put into a text file, seperated with comma?

Tags: regex, tcl, expect

```
set line { 
Jul 24 21:06:40 2014: %AUTH-6-INFO: login[1765]: user 'admin' on 'pts/1' logged
Jul 24 21:05:15 2014: %DATAPLANE-5-: Unrecognized HTTP URL www.58.net. Flow: 0x2
Jul 24 21:04:39 2014: %DATAPLANE-5-: Unrecognized HTTP URL static.58.com. Flow:
Jul 24 21:04:38 2014: %DATAPLANE-5-: Unrecognized HTTP URL www.google-analytics.com. Flow: 0x2265394048.
Jul 24 21:04:36 2014: %DATAPLANE-5-: Unrecognized HTTP URL track.58.co.in. Flow: 0
Jul 24 21:04:38 2014: %DATAPLANE-5-:Unrecognized HTTP URL www.google.co.in. Flow: 0x87078800
Jul 24 21:04:38 2014: %DATAPLANE-5-:CCB:44:Unrecognized Client Hello ServerName www.google.co.in. Flow: 0x87073880. len_analyzed: 183
Jul 24 21:04:38 2014: %DATAPLANE-5-:CCB:44:Unrecognized Server Hello ServerName test1. Flow: 0x87073880, len_analyzed 99
Jul 24 21:04:38 2014: %DATAPLANE-5-:CCB:44:Unrecognized Server Cert CommonName *.google.com. Flow: 0x87073880
Jul 24 21:04:38 2014: %DATAPLANE-5-:CCB:44:Searching rname(TYPE_A) cs50.wac.edgecastcdn.net in dns_hash_table
Jul 24 21:04:38 2014: %DATAPLANE-5-:Unrecognized HTTP URL www.facebook.com. Flow: 0x87078800
Jul 24 21:04:38 2014: %DATAPLANE-5-:CCB:44:Unrecognized Client Hello ServerName www.fb.com. Flow: 0x87073880. len_analyzed: 183
Jul 24 21:05:38 2014: %DATAPLANE-5-:CCB:44:Unrecognized Server Hello ServerName test. Flow: 0x87073880, len_analyzed 99
Jul 24 21:04:38 2014: %DATAPLANE-5-:CCB:44:Unrecognized Server Cert CommonName *.facebook.com. Flow: 0x87073880
Jul 24 21:05:39 2014: %DATAPLANE-5-:CCB:44:Searching rname(TYPE_A) cs50.wac.facebook.net in dns_hash_table
}

        set urls [list]
        foreach {dummy item} [regexp -all -inline {Server Hello ServerName\s+(\S+)} $line] {
        lappend urls $item
        }
        #puts $res
            set s "*****************************************************"
            set f {}
            set f [open output.txt a]
            if {$f ne {}} {

            foreach url $urls {
            chan puts $f $url

            }
            chan puts $f $s
            chan close $f
            }
```

How to grep "URL", "Client Hello ServerName", "Server Hello ServerName", "Server Cert CommonName", "rname" from the above variable $line. and upload this to text file, sepertated by comma.

EDITED:

output.txt contents should be :

www.58.net,www.google.co.in,test1.,*.google.com.,cs50.wac.edgecastcdn.net

where "www.58.net" is the output grepped using URL.
      "www.google.co.in" is the output grepped using Client Hello ServerName etc

Thanks,

Balu P.

Comment: Is that what you got in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25158680/tcl-regexphow-to-grep-5-diifferent-words-from-a-variable-using-tcl-regexp-and/25160818#25160818 ?

Comment: Hi Dinesh, I want the output in a single line sepearated with commas. Eg : string1,str2,str3,str4,str5. How to print the next grepped output in a same line seperated by comma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can capture the URLs and from the result list then join on commas. A simplistic approach would be like...

```
set urls [list]
foreach {dummy item} [regexp -all -inline {Server Hello ServerName\s+(\S+)} $line] {
    lappend urls $item
}
set urls [join $urls ,]
```

Though if there can be commas in the urls, you might add quotes and escape any inherent quotes in there too...

```
set urls [list]
foreach {dummy item} [regexp -all -inline {Server Hello ServerName\s+(\S+)} $line] {
    lappend urls \"[string map {{"} {\"}} $item]\"
}
set urls [join $urls ,]
```

The `string map` will escape any quotes with a backslash here.

You might instead use tabs instead of commas to avoid these:

```
set urls [list]
foreach {dummy item} [regexp -all -inline {Server Hello ServerName\s+(\S+)} $line] {
    lappend urls $item
}
set urls [join $urls \t]
```

---

EDIT: From chat, here's the full code with all the other different implications and using a modified version of [Donal's regexp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25160818/1578604):

```
set line { 
Jul 24 21:06:40 2014: %AUTH-6-INFO: login[1765]: user 'admin' on 'pts/1' logged
Jul 24 21:05:15 2014: %DATAPLANE-5-: Unrecognized HTTP URL www.58.net. Flow: 0x2
Jul 24 21:04:39 2014: %DATAPLANE-5-: Unrecognized HTTP URL static.58.com. Flow:
Jul 24 21:04:38 2014: %DATAPLANE-5-: Unrecognized HTTP URL www.google-analytics.
com. Flow: 0x2265394048.
Jul 24 21:04:36 2014: %DATAPLANE-5-: Unrecognized HTTP URL track.58.co.in. Flow: 0
Jul 24 21:04:38 2014: %DATAPLANE-5-:Unrecognized HTTP URL www.google.co.in. Flow: 0x87078800
Jul 24 21:04:38 2014: %DATAPLANE-5-:CCB:44:Unrecognized Client Hello ServerName www.google.co.in. Flow: 0x87073880. len_analyzed: 183
Jul 24 21:04:38 2014: %DATAPLANE-5-:CCB:44:Unrecognized Server Hello ServerName test1. Flow: 0x87073880, len_analyzed 99
Jul 24 21:04:38 2014: %DATAPLANE-5-:CCB:44:Unrecognized Server Cert CommonName *.google.com. Flow: 0x87073880
Jul 24 21:04:38 2014: %DATAPLANE-5-:CCB:44:Searching rname(TYPE_A) cs50.wac.edgecastcdn.net in dns_hash_table
Jul 24 21:04:38 2014: %DATAPLANE-5-:Unrecognized HTTP URL www.facebook.com. Flow: 0x87078800
Jul 24 21:04:38 2014: %DATAPLANE-5-:CCB:44:Unrecognized Client Hello ServerName www.fb.com. Flow: 0x87073880. len_analyzed: 183
Jul 24 21:05:38 2014: %DATAPLANE-5-:CCB:44:Unrecognized Server Hello ServerName test. Flow: 0x87073880, len_analyzed 99
Jul 24 21:04:38 2014: %DATAPLANE-5-:CCB:44:Unrecognized Server Cert CommonName *.facebook.com. Flow: 0x87073880
Jul 24 21:05:39 2014: %DATAPLANE-5-:CCB:44:Searching rname(TYPE_A) cs50.wac.facebook.net in dns_hash_table
}

set URL [list]
set chs [list]
set shs [list]
set scs [list]
set rname [list]
set cURL 0
set cchs 0
set cshs 0
set cscs 0
set crname 0
foreach {whole type payload} [regexp -all -inline {(?x)
    \y ( URL
      | (?: Client | Server)[ ]Hello[ ]ServerName
      | Server[ ]Cert[ ]CommonName
      | rname\([^)]+\) )
    \s+ ((?:(?![ ]Flow:| in[ ]dns_hash_table).)+)
} $line] {
    switch -regexp $type {
        URL {lappend URL $payload; incr cURL}
        {Client Hello ServerName} {lappend chs $payload; incr cchs}
        {Server Hello ServerName} {lappend shs $payload; incr cshs}
        {Server Cert CommonName} {lappend scs $payload; incr cscs}
        {rname\([^)]+\)} {lappend rname $payload; incr crname}
    }
}

set max [lindex [lsort -decreasing [list $cURL $cchs $cshs $cscs $crname]] 0]
set i 0
set all_list [list]

while {$max != $i} {
    if {[catch {regsub -all {\s} [lindex $URL $i] "" one}]} {set one ""}
    if {[catch {regsub -all {\s} [lindex $chs $i] "" two}]} {set two ""}
    if {[catch {regsub -all {\s} [lindex $shs $i] "" three}]} {set three ""}
    if {[catch {regsub -all {\s} [lindex $scs $i] "" four}]} {set four ""}
    if {[catch {regsub -all {\s} [lindex $rname $i] "" five}]} {set five ""}
    lappend all_list [join [list $one $two $three $four $five] ,]
    incr i
}
puts [join $all_list \n]
```

[ideone demo](http://ideone.com/CBz6WG)

Comment: Hi Jerry, Thanks for your answer. But I want to have output like : strring1,string2,string3,string4,string5. Where string1 is "HTTP URL" and string2 is "Client Hello ServerName" and string3 is "Server Hello ServerName" and string4 is "Server Cert CommonName" and string5 is "rname(TYPE_A)". Please help me to get output like this.

Comment: @balu That's an issue with the regex you're currently using. From your question, what is the full output you want to get? Could you put that in your question (don't put it in comments, it's difficult to understand).

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. I have edited my question with the required output.

Comment: @balu I'm sorry, but I don't understand. `static.58.com` is not in the output even if it is an HTTP URL? Or does that mean you are taking only the first HTTP URL, the first Client Hello ServerName, the first Server Hello ServerName, the first Server Cert CommonName and the first rname(TYPE_A)?

Comment: Whatever grepped first. its should be in first line. Eg : www.58.net  ,  www.google.co.in  ,  test1.  ,  *.google.com.  ,  cs50.wac.edgecastcdn.net. If some field is not there it can be empty. Eg : static.58.com,,,,,. (here only static.58.com is found, no other fileds found) .

Comment: @balu Ok, then I think it's better to use one regex for each. I edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks jerry. Its really helps to solve my problem. Is there a way to grep all such things in $line. Now its grepping only the first one right . Should I put this code in foreach?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58898/discussion-between-balu-and-jerry).