# How to avoid printing unwanted lines in the attached TCL script

Tags: regex, tcl

Please find the code in the below link : written by [Jerry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25179232/1578604) yesterday for my requirement:

http://ideone.com/CBz6WG.

It's working when I use the $line variable (that is there in that script). When I replace `$line` contents with the following lines, `regexp` yields some unneeded output.

```
set line {

test-443670#show logging


Logging module: enabled

    Aggregation time: disabled

    Console logging: level debugging

    Monitor logging: disabled

    Buffered logging: level debugging

    Syslog logging: level debugging

        Facility: local7


Log Buffer (5003 bytes):



Aug 08 15:44:02 2014: %DATAPLANE-5-: Searching rname(TYPE_A) qweplost.com in dns

_hash_table.

Aug 08 15:43:58 2014: %DATAPLANE-5-: Unrecognized HTTP URL www.google-analytics.

com. Flow: 0x8707e380.

Aug 08 15:43:58 2014: %DATAPLANE-5-: Unrecognized HTTP URL www.google-analytics.

com. Flow: 0x8707e380.

Aug 08 15:43:58 2014: %DATAPLANE-5-: Searching rname(TYPE_A) ocsp.verisign.net i

n dns_hash_table.

Aug 08 15:43:58 2014: %DATAPLANE-5-: Searching rname(TYPE_A) www-google-analytic

s.l.google.com in dns_hash_table.

Aug 08 15:43:58 2014: %DATAPLANE-5-: Searching rname(TYPE_A) www-google-analytic

s.l.google.com in dns_hash_table.

Aug 08 15:43:58 2014: %DATAPLANE-5-: Searching rname(TYPE_A) www-google-analytic

s.l.google.com in dns_hash_table.

Aug 08 15:43:58 2014: %DATAPLANE-5-: Searching rname(TYPE_A) www-google-analytic

s.l.google.com in dns_hash_table.

Aug 08 15:43:58 2014: %DATAPLANE-5-: Searching rname(TYPE_A) www-google-analytic

s.l.google.com in dns_hash_table.

Aug 08 15:43:58 2014: %DATAPLANE-5-: Searching rname(TYPE_A) www-google-analytic

s.l.google.com in dns_hash_table.

Aug 08 15:43:58 2014: %DATAPLANE-5-: Searching rname(TYPE_A) www-google-analytic

s.l.google.com in dns_hash_table.

Aug 08 15:43:58 2014: %DATAPLANE-5-: Searching rname(TYPE_A) www-google-analytic

s.l.google.com in dns_hash_table.

Aug 08 15:43:58 2014: %DATAPLANE-5-: Searching rname(TYPE_A) www-google-analytic

s.l.google.com in dns_hash_table.

Aug 08 15:43:58 2014: %DATAPLANE-5-: Searching rname(TYPE_A) www-google-analytic

s.l.google.com in dns_hash_table.

Aug 08 15:43:58 2014: %DATAPLANE-5-: Searching rname(TYPE_A) www-google-analytic

s.l.google.com in dns_hash_table.

Aug 08 15:43:57 2014: %DATAPLANE-5-: Searching rname(TYPE_AAAA) www-google-analy

tics.l.google.com in dns_hash_table.

Aug 08 15:43:57 2014: %DATAPLANE-5-: Unrecognized HTTP URL www.babelgum.com. Flo

w: 0x8706ed80.

Aug 08 15:43:57 2014: %DATAPLANE-5-: Unrecognized Server Cert CommonName RapidSS

L CA. Flow: 0x87073e80.

Aug 08 15:43:57 2014: %DATAPLANE-5-: Unrecognized Server Cert CommonName GeoTrus

t Global CA. Flow: 0x87073e80.

Aug 08 15:43:57 2014: %DATAPLANE-5-: Unrecognized Server Cert CommonName *.elite

modellook.com. Flow: 0x87073e80.

Aug 08 15:43:57 2014: %DATAPLANE-5-: Unrecognized Server Cert CommonName RapidSS

L CA. Flow: 0x87073e80.

Aug 08 15:43:57 2014: %DATAPLANE-5-: Unrecognized HTTP URL www.babelgum.com. Flo

w: 0x8706ed80.

Aug 08 15:43:57 2014: %DATAPLANE-5-: Unrecognized Client Hello ServerName ?www.b

abelgum.com. Flow: 0x87073e80. len_analyzed: 183.

Aug 08 15:43:57 2014: %DATAPLANE-5-: Unrecognized HTTP URL www.babelgum.com. Flo

w: 0x8706ed80.

Aug 08 15:43:57 2014: %DATAPLANE-5-: Searching rname(TYPE_A) elite-862037136.eu-

west-1.elb.amazonaws.com in dns_hash_table.

Aug 08 15:43:57 2014: %DATAPLANE-5-: Searching rname(TYPE_A) elite-862037136.eu-

west-1.elb.amazonaws.com in dns_hash_table.

Aug 08 15:43:53 2014: ap622-443670 : %SYSTEM-6-CONFIG_REVISION: Configuration re

vision updated to 36 from 35

Aug 08 15:43:53 2014: ap622-443670 : %SYSTEM-6-CONFIG_REVISION: Configuration re

vision updated to 35 from 34

Aug 08 15:43:53 2014: ap622-443670 : %SYSTEM-6-CONFIG_COMMIT: Configuration comm

it by user 'admin' (mapsh) from '127.0.0.1'

Aug 08 15:43:48 2014: ap622-443670 : %SYSTEM-5-LOGIN: Successfully logged in use

r 'admin' with privilege 'superuser' from 'pts/0'

Aug 08 15:43:48 2014: %AUTH-6-INFO: login[5597]: user 'admin' on 'pts/0' logged

in

Aug 08 15:43:42 2014: %DATAPLANE-5-: Searching rname(TYPE_A) qweplost.com in dns

_hash_table.

Aug 08 15:43:28 2014: %DATAPLANE-5-: Searching rname(TYPE_A) google.com in dns_h

ash_table.

Aug 08 15:43:28 2014: %DATAPLANE-5-: Searching rname(TYPE_A) google.com in dns_h

ash_table.

Aug 08 15:43:28 2014: %DATAPLANE-5-: Searching rname(TYPE_A) google.com in dns_h

ash_table.

Aug 08 15:43:28 2014: %DATAPLANE-5-: Searching rname(TYPE_A) google.com in dns_h

ash_table.

Aug 08 15:43:28 2014: %DATAPLANE-5-: Searching rname(TYPE_A) google.com in dns_h

ash_table.

Aug 08 15:43:28 2014: %DATAPLANE-5-: Searching rname(TYPE_A) google.com in dns_h

ash_table.

Aug 08 15:43:28 2014: %DATAPLANE-5-: Searching rname(TYPE_A) google.com in dns_h

ash_table.

Aug 08 15:43:28 2014: %DATAPLANE-5-: Searching rname(TYPE_A) google.com in dns_h

ash_table.

Aug 08 15:43:28 2014: %DATAPLANE-5-: Searching rname(TYPE_A) google.com in dns_h

ash_table.

Aug 08 15:43:28 2014: %DATAPLANE-5-: Searching rname(TYPE_A) google.com in dns_h

ash_table.

Aug 08 15:43:28 2014: %DATAPLANE-5-: Searching rname(TYPE_A) google.com in dns_h

ash_table.

Aug 08 15:43:11 2014: %DATAPLANE-5-: Searching rname(TYPE_A) zeplost.com in dns_

hash_table.

Aug 08 15:42:50 2014: %DATAPLANE-5-: Searching rname(TYPE_A) zeplost.com in dns_

hash_table.

Aug 08 15:42:20 2014: %DATAPLANE-5-: Searching rname(TYPE_A) replost.com in dns_

hash_table.

Aug 08 15:41:59 2014: %DATAPLANE-5-: Searching rname(TYPE_A) replost.com in dns_

hash_table.

Aug 08 15:39:46 2014: ap622-443670 : %SYSTEM-6-LOGOUT: Logged out user 'admin' w

ith privilege 'superuser' from '127.0.0.1'

}
```

STEPS TO REPRODUCE THE ISSUE:

1. Run the script that is there in "http://ideone.com/CBz6WG.". You will see the clear output each with seperated by comma.
2. Now change the contents of $line to above given contents.

It's giving some unwanted lines.

I tried lot to fix this, but I am unable to.

Could any of you, help me on this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it'll be easy to adapt the regex to that situation as this is an inherent issue with the input. I suggest thus removing all newlines from the input first:

```
regsub -all {[\r\n]} $line "" line
foreach {whole type payload} {...}
```

[ideone demo](http://ideone.com/ntvsdN)